# What general function can I use to represent the next sequence: 2,2,2,2,2,3,3,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,2,2,2,2,2,3,3…?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Look at this sequence:

```
2,2,2,2,2,3,3,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,2,2,2,2,2,3,3...
```

It is defined as follows:

$$f(n)=\begin{cases}
3 &\text{if $n \bmod 7=6,0$}\\
2 &\text{otherwise}\\
\end{cases}$$

David found a good [representation](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1124548/101178) for $f(n)$:

$$g(n)=\frac{\sin\dfrac{2\pi(n+1)}{7}}{\sin\dfrac{2\pi}{7}}
   \frac{\sin\dfrac{2\pi(n+2)}{7}}{\sin\dfrac{4\pi}{7}}\cdots
   \frac{\sin\dfrac{2\pi(n+6)}{7}}{\sin\dfrac{12\pi}{7}}\ ;$$

$$f(n)=2+g(n)+g(n+1)\ ;$$

What is a general representation of $f(n)$ that defined as fallow:

$$f'(n)=\begin{cases}
a &\text{if $n \bmod c=0$ or in the range of  $\{c-d,c-1\}$}\\
b &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

- $a,b,c,d$ are known positive integeres

To be more specific I have

$$h(n)=y - \sum_{0}^{n}{f'(n)}$$

- $y$ is a know positive integer

And $h(n)$ is defined as fallow:
$$h(n) = \frac{e}{n}$$

- $e$ is a known positive integer

How do I find $n$?

Comment: Why this question is asked [again](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1124532/what-function-can-i-use-to-represent-the-next-sequence-2-2-2-2-2-3-3-2-2-2-2-2?lq=1)?

Comment: The section starting "To be more specific" is very confusing, $f(n)$ takes two values, $h(n)$ takes infinitely many different values, yet $h(n)=f(n)$?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews is it more clear now?

Comment: Well, a function of only integer variables doesn't have a derivative, but a periodic function of a real variable has a periodic derivative, so it's not clear what you are taking about.

Comment: The sequence in the title it is one example of what $f'(n)$ could be looks like. In reality I have a big collection of data and many such sequences that I need to compare to $h(n)$ for possible much. All this is part of my algorithm for [integer factorization](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1118529/integer-factorization-possible-progress).

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Possible much in my algorithm is where $n$ is a factor of $c$

Comment: @user170039 Ilya has expanded the question to ask for further details about an answer that was given to the previous question. That is a perfectly reasonable thing to do.

Comment: But this question still doesn't make sense. @MJD

Comment: That is a separate issue.

Comment: @MJD Sorry I had an error in the question, I understand why it made a confusion. Please tell me if it is good structured now?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand what you are asking, we can define
$$
\newcommand{\flfrac}[2]{\left\lfloor\frac{#1}{#2}\right\rfloor}
f(n)=b+(a-b)\left(\flfrac{n+d}c-\flfrac{n-1}c\right)\tag{1}
$$
then
$$
f(n)=\left\{\begin{array}{}
a&\text{if }n\equiv c-d\dots c\pmod{c}\\
b&\text{if }n\equiv1\dots c-d-1\pmod{c}
\end{array}\right.\tag{2}
$$
Next we compute
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^n\flfrac km
&=\sum_{k=0}^{qm-1+r+1}\flfrac km\\
&=\overbrace{m\frac{(\color{#0000FF}{q}-1)\color{#0000FF}{q}}2}^{\text{$m$ copies of $0\dots q-1$}}+\overbrace{(\color{#C00000}{r}+1)\color{#0000FF}{q}\vphantom{\frac{()}2}}^{\text{$r+1$ copies of $q$}}\\
&=\left(\frac{m\left(\color{#0000FF}{\flfrac nm}-1\right)}2+\color{#C00000}{n-m\flfrac nm}+1\right)\color{#0000FF}{\flfrac nm}\\
&=\left(n+1-\frac{m\left(\flfrac nm+1\right)}2\right)\flfrac nm\tag{3}
\end{align}
$$
Now, apply $(3)$ to
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^n\left(\flfrac{k+d}c-\flfrac{k-1}c\right)
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n+d}\flfrac kc-\sum_{k=0}^{d-1}\flfrac kc-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\flfrac kc+\sum_{k=0}^{-2}\flfrac kc\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n+d}\flfrac kc-\sum_{k=0}^{d-1}\flfrac kc-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\flfrac kc+1\tag{4}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: What are $q,r$?

Comment: Note that $n=qm+r$ and that we are talking about division by $m$. If that doesn't ring a bell, think about **q**uotients and **r**emainders.